Umid butunligi 0125


Formula:N-N=Z

, bu yerda:N natural son
Z butun son

Shartlar:

\begin{cases} 
   \text{Agar } a, b \in \mathbb{N}, \; \text{unda} \; a - b \in \mathbb{Z}, \\
   a - b = 0, \; \text{agar} \; a = b, \\
   a - b > 0, \; \text{agar} \; a > b, \\
   a - b < 0, \; \text{agar} \; a < b. 
   \end{cases}

Misollar:

\begin{aligned}
   & 5 - 5 = 0 \quad (\in \mathbb{Z}), \\
   & 5 - 4 = 1 \quad (\in \mathbb{Z}), \\
   & 5 - 6 = -1 \quad (\in \mathbb{Z}). 
   \end{aligned}

Qo'shimcha mulohaza:

\forall a, b \in \mathbb{N}, ; (a - b) \in \mathbb{Z}.

